# Best way to move an image across part of the screen?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have a Silverlight WP7 app and an image on my page that I want to appear to slide across the screen. What is the best way of doing this? I wrote this real quick but the UI doesn't update until the entire method is done.

```
    private void SpinImg(Image img, double left) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            img.Margin = new Thickness(left, img.Margin.Top + 1, 0, 0);
            if(img.Margin.Top > 314) {
                //move it to the top
                img.Margin = new Thickness(left, -105, 0, 0);
            }
            int wait = 1000 / i;
            Thread.Sleep(wait);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Storyboard - this is hardware-acceleratable, and all occurs on the Render thread, so you'll see much better performance than trying to update position directly over and over.

Storyboard has the advantage of being time-based instead of frame-based, so it's easy to declare "I want the image to move from  to  in 0.5 seconds" and it will just happen.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep will freeze ALL UI processing, use Dispatcher class.